# Prevent Ionic CLI from running resource generation on platform-add

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When adding a Cordova platform through the Ionic CLI, e.g. `ionic cordova platform add android`, Ionic executes two commands:

1. `cordova platform add android --save`
2. `ionic cordova resources android --force`

However, I keep already generated resources under version control, and use a slightly different setup.
Thus, I don't want to re-generate those during platform-add, as it not only does unnecessary work but also messes up my *config.xml*.
**How can I prevent the second command from being run?**

Alternatively, could I register a hook to be executed after `ionic cordova resources` for cleanup? The Cordova hook `after_platform_add` is useless, as it would get executed before the resources task.

#### Workaround

Generating resources can be suppressed by using the `--no-resources` flag when adding a platform.
However, I'm still looking for a permanent, canonical solution.